# Richedit Msftedit strange border

Tags: c++, winapi, styles, border, richedit

I get really strange behavior when I use more than one RichEdit control:

[image: The first richedit is the bottom one]

```
LoadLibrary("Msftedit.dll");
RichEdit = CreateWindow("RICHEDIT50W", "", ES_READONLY | ES_MULTILINE | WS_HSCROLL | WS_VSCROLL | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER | WS_TABSTOP, 5, 370, 600, 300, hwnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);

RichEdit2 = CreateWindow("RICHEDIT50W", "", /*0x550081C4*/ 0x50810804, 610, 65, 600, 300, hwnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

The first EditControl works as it should, however the second one has some strange border around it.
First I tried to use the same styles as for the first richedit, then I found out the style using Spy++.
Even if I have the same styles, I get different results, probably the same as if I used WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE extended style for the second richedit. 
I even tried to free the library and load it again, but with the same result.

Thank You all in advance!

Comment: Might have something to do with which child window has input focus.

Comment: But if I focus on the first RichEdit, the border stays on the second one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured it out. I have no Idea why, but the second RichEdit is somehow getting the WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE style after is created, so I simply remove the style like so:

```
LONG lExStyle = GetWindowLong(RichEdit2, GWL_EXSTYLE);
lExStyle &= ~WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE;
SetWindowLong(RichEdit2, GWL_EXSTYLE, lExStyle);
```

Now the RichEdit looks the same as the first one. But I have really no idea, where the style comes from.